# How to write a textbox.text value into XML file in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

In my winform application, user can able to select folderpath using browse button. This folder path will be displayed in textbox1 control. How to save this folderpath into an XML file when user clicked on Save button. If possible give me sample code in VB.NET. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim e As New XElement("FilePath", text1.Text)
File.WriteAllText("somefilename.xml", e.ToString())
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort.I appreciate. I explained in more detail in my recent question. So can you please answer that as soon as you can.